# How to get default navigation (with standard remote) when I open a web page

Tags: javascript, flash, samsung-smart-tv

I have a js/flash Samsung TV App which needs to open remote server web page, and then let user browse from there. This is a requirement so I can not do it all within our app.

I can open a page by simply calling 
window.location = newLocation;
this does go to remote location and displays it on screen.
But I can not navigate around with standard remote!

I tried with all the keys registered and unregistered (pluginAPI.unregistAllKey();) no change what so ever.

Is there any way of calling default browser, or enabling standard (although awkward) remote navigation on a page I open?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call default browser. Default `Web Browser` is standalone application, separate from SmartTV SDK.

You can make `<iframe>` with page you need and implement controls yourself. Samsung browser don't have cross origin rescriction, so you can have full access to `<iframe>` content.

Comment: But still no navigation, I just tested it and no way to control standard web pages in iframe...

Comment: There is no builtin way to control web page, you need to implement controls yourself. You need to listen to key events and make your own navigation for loaded page.

Comment: But if i do not control loaded pages at all?
This is a service i use.
Could I move controls on their pages, use imei input for text fields etc.
Remember I have no controls over their pages!!

Comment: you have access to `iframe.contentWindow.document`, you can modify it, add your own script to implement navigation

Comment: Uh, that is credit card processing, not sure if I am allowed to do that. But yes, You are right that can be done, even if it is a bit more work.
Hm, perhaps somebody did it already?

Comment: You should consult with your payment provider, maybe you need to make custom form for TV, that you will open in `iframe`.

Comment: You are correct and we are already doing that, but they are large and I do not think we have sufficient leverage to make them do that :)

Comment: They should have different forms for mobile devices, this is just another platform to support. If they do not want to do it, you just need to find another provider for payments from TV. In our application we use chronopay.com as payment provider.